# I have changed dropdown menu created from select and option tag to a Hoverable Dropdown menu. How should i pass values in it

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I want to create a Hoverable Dropdown to sort my results by name or date dynamically. Previously i had a dropdown created by using  and  tag in which everything was working fine

My code was:

```
<select name="sort-by" id="sort">
      <option value="name" <?php if($orderby == 'name') echo "selected='selected'";?>>name</option>
      <option value="date" <?php if($orderby == 'date') echo "selected='selected'";?>>date</option>
    </select>
```

which i have changed to

```
    <div class="sort">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">date</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

which has converted to a Hoverable Dropdown. But now the problem is how would the code know that i have clicked on a link and hence pass a value $orderby which i am fetching on another page by using if(isset($_POST[order_by])) to use in a sql query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry @kanayo, but this isn't working or maybe i am not keeping it in correct way. Is this the right way to keep it

```
    <div class="sort">
    <script>
    $('ul li a').click(function(){
    newValue = $(this).html();
    $('input#order_by').val(newValue);
    });
    </script>
    </div>
    <ul>
    <input type="hidden" id="order_by" name="order_by" value=""/>
    <li><a href="#" >Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Date</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Lol. Its exactly same with my answer. You do it with both. But note. If it doesn't work then its either you haven't included the jQuery library or you have a syntax error

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JavaScript` or `jQuery` to achieve that. First you create a hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_by" name="order_by" value="" />
```

Then you use `jQuery` to update the `value` of the `input` field when the user clicks any option like this

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
    newValue = $(this).html();
    $('input#order_by').val(newValue);
});
```

Note: Don't forget to include the `jQuery` library to your script. And also remember that your input field have to be within the `form` tag that you are submitting.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqgnpga9/) to display the result